# Numpy's real-FFT and fftshift

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have an image in Fourier space, that looks like (real part):[image]

I want to get the real space picture through numpy's irfft2: So what i show here is np.fft.irfft2 of the previous image:

[image]

My intuition may be off, but through numpy's conventions for the output of the fft and inverse-fft, respectively, shouldn't the image in real space be concentric circles - centered in the middle? There seems to be a fftshift that shouldn't be there to my mind